# How do I mask UITextfield with prefix?

Tags: ios, swift, uikit

Simply I need to have UITextField with some prefix, f.e `+48` and then masked phone number like this `___ ___ ___`. How can I do this in code? The result in UItextField should look like `+48 ___ ___ ___` and only the places with `_` should be editable.

I use NSString+Mask cocoapod:

```
let textField = UITextFieldMask()
textField.mask = NSStringMask(pattern: "(\\d{3}) (\\d{3}) (\\d{3})", placeholder: "_")
```

But the result after presenting is the following:

[image]

After I styrt typing it looks like (why not just after view is loaded?):

[image]

but no prefix here. Why?

Comment: try this txtEdit.becomeFirstResponder() on load

Comment: Maybe it helps: https://github.com/seaburg/FormattedTextField

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind adding external dependencies, this library solves your problem and gives you even more amazing options:

https://github.com/marmelroy/PhoneNumberKit

[image: PhoneNumberKit demonstration]

Comment: Not exactly solves my problem. As you can see I need to have `_` still visible while entering phone number for empty places... but here you have not this. Second thing I need to use it in more general way, not only for phone numbers but for `___ ___` or `__-___`.